# Lambda function distinct parameters

Tags: lisp

I'm trying to create lambda functions that use the same code but have different Internal parameters.
To clarify, I'm putting here the code:

```
(defun testes ()
(setf lol '())
 (loop for i in (list 1 2 3 4 5 )
        do (loop for j in (list 1 2 3 4 5)
        do (setf lol (append lol (list (cons i j))))))  


lol

)

(defun mainff ()
 (setf lol (testes))
 (setf res ())
 (print lol)
 (loop for i in lol
    do (setf res (append res (list #'(lambda ()
                        (print i)
                        ))))
 )
 res
)

(defun fun()
 (setf res (mainff))

 (loop for i in res
    do (funcall i)
 )
)
```

Returning to the inicial question, i in the append of res must be unique to each lambda that is created. However it only saves the last value that it assumes (5 5). Any way to solve this?

Comment: Where are your variables declared? `res` and `lol` are not declared. That's an error. You also want to format and indent your code properly. Appending to the end of a list is bad. Downvoted for lack of effort to write good code.

Comment: these are just tests no my actual code. Just a simplified example of a much complicated code. And about the indention, it was when i posted here.

Comment: there is no excuse for writing sloppy code. Editors do the indentation, proper code is more readable. Basically your way makes it much harder to write correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LET` to create a different binding for each `i`.

```
(loop for element in list
      ...

        (let ((i element))
           (lambda ()
             (print i)))

      ...

      )
```